# Unknown word error after importing leaflet css file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, leaflet, react-leaflet

When I import the leaflet.css file into my Map.tsx, it throws an error:
CssSyntaxError: .../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css:1:1: Unknown word

Maybe it's a useful information that I runnig Storybook to see the component.If I try to import the CSS there I got the same result.

Obviously, without the CSS it's not working.
I have no clue what's the problem and nothing helped yet.

```
"dependencies":
    "leaflet": "^1.9.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
```

Map.tsx

```
import './map.module.scss'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import * as React from "react";

export const Map = () => {
    return (
        ...
    );
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // .js and .jsx files
                exclude: /node_modules/, // excluding the node_modules folder
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // styles files
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install react-leaflet` ?

Comment: yes, `npm install leaflet react-leaflet`

Comment: "React, React DOM and Leaflet are required peer dependencies. You must add them to your project if they are not already installed:" (from react leaflet website). Do you have all of those installed as well? Can you show your package.json file?

Comment: Yes. Everything installed what I need. It's a bigger project, and this is the only problem in it.